# weka multiple vectors for same instance

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am working on a seizure prediction research, and I am using Weka to train my data vectors on.

If I have 10 seizures, each seizure is represented by 5 vectors, which makes a total of 50 vectors corresponding to 10 seizures. However, Weka is treating these vectors as totally independent even though each 5 vectors corresponds to only one seizure.

So how can I let Weka take this into account when performing the Learning?

Comment: Are you using the GUI or programming using the Weka library?

Comment: why don't you just merge all the 5 vectors to a single vector?

Comment: NBartley I am using GUI.

Comment: Thomas because I am going to test the model generated with single vectors ( having the length as a single vector ). If I merge the 5 vectors then I should input that length of vectors which I don't want

Comment: I don't know the insights of your problems so this might be stupid - can't you consider instances as classes ? What I mean in arff file , just give same label to all 5 vectors of each class.